# Impacts of the collapse of the current cyber-security?

Tags: technology, near-future, mathematics, internet, security

Much of the information transferred over the internet is encrypted using methods which rely on the fact that currently, very large numbers are extremely difficult to factor. Imagine that in the near future, developments in mathematics result in algorithms can factor numbers in a fraction of a second (which is actually possible). How much would "life as we know it", with online banking, communication, etc. change? Would these industries be able to quickly develop other methods of encryption, or would the world get kicked back to pre-internet days?

Comment: The premise stated in the question does not necessarily imply the outcome given in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one answer to this, because it is too complicated of a topic.  The key to the answer would be in global dynamics.  How does China respond?  How does Russia respond?  How does ISIS respond?  How does Anonymous respond?

Rest assured, very little encryption relies on the difficulty of factoring large composite numbers.  Most symmetric algorithms rely on other proofs for their security.  The facet of encryption that would be pounded would be public-key encryption, where RSA is the current reigning champion.

There are other public-key encryptions out there.  Some even rely on lattice based techniques that are immune to Shor's algorithm, making them particularly resilient against quantum computers.  In the greater scheme of things, the internet can survive someone determining how to rapidly factor a large composite number.

However, in that short period during the changeover, there would be a lot of turmoil.  The individual players on this global scene would have a lot to say about how things play out.

Comment: "There is no one answer to this, because it is too complicated of a topic." - this question is **obviously** too broad/opinion based and should not have been answered. Cort, you're one of the top users of WB, and it pains me to see you setting a bad example T.T

Comment: RSA has long been broken; there was a security break a few years ago which released their algorithms. Unfortunately, it doesn't stop corporations from relying on RSA tokens.

Comment: @Aify I felt there was a class of answers, and describing the class seemed like a useful enough answer.  A hundred people could write a hundred books about different ways it could play out, but the reality of the world of cryptography is clear enough that those hundred books would have to fit a pretty crisp timeline from 0-day exploit to restitution of order.  The way that stage was set and the eventual endpoint deemed valuable for many future authors.

Comment: @Marion In the context of public key encryption, RSA is an algorithm for encryption that involves large prime numbers.  It was actually released the day it was published.  A good crypto algorithm assumes the enemy already has your algorithm, so there is no breach when it is released.  The people who developed RSA then founded a company, also named RSA.  Obviously this was to enjoy the fruits of their successful algorithm, but it does create some confusion, especially with respect to their security breach.

Comment: I was under the assumption that elliptic curve crypto uses a different math method than the factoring of large almost prime numbers. Are you postulating all methods of crypto math have been broken, or just the crypto that uses slow factoring of large numbers?

Comment: @MarkRipley The RSA algorithm bases its security on the difficulty of factoring semiprimes (the product of two prime numbers). (That's not to say there's no easier way to attack RSA than semiprime factorization; *we just haven't found one yet.*) Cort Ammon mentioned lattice-based algorithms, which rely on a totally different set of problems. There's also elliptic-curve cryptography, which relies on another set of problems: discrete logarithms. It's possible, but not necessarily a given, that an efficient method of factoring semiprimes could generalize also to solving discrete logarithms.

Comment: @MarkRipley The question asked about just factoring large composite numbers.  Breaking all of crypto would be a more substantial hit, and probably would not have a meaningful worldbuilding answer.   Elliptic curve crypto (ECC) is interesting.  From my understanding (which is by no means perfect), ECC is very strong.  However, Dual EC DRBG, an ECC pushed by the NSA, demonstrated an interesting issue with them: they're terribly easy to hide backdoors in.  That would suggest they may be secure, but they can't be trusted =)

Comment: @CortAmmon That's why current opinion is that the curves should be selected in a highly transparent manner, in ways that involve no (or minimal) "magic constants". It's unexplained magic constants that provide opportunities for hiding back doors; if you tell people exactly how you chose the proposed constants, and ideally do so in a cryptographically secure fashion, there's really no good place to hide a back door. For example, an ECC curve involving just `SHA512("Cort Ammon does not fully trust Dual EC DRBG")` and the digits of $\pi$ is probably not a good candidate for hiding a back door in.

Comment: Also, just for clarity: I'm not saying that an ECC curve made up of those constants would be *secure*. I don't know elliptic-curve cryptography well enough for that. However, you'd very likely have a hard time coming up with ways of hiding a backdoor in a curve generated in such a transparent fashion.

Comment: @CortAmmon, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Cort's answer and I think it is the correct one. This one is just me bringing more info to the table.

There is a matter of scale involved. We usually hear about encryption keys with some amount of bits attached. That's the size of the key, and the longer it is, the more computing it takes to break.

Adding four extra bits to an encryption alghoritm will, on back-of-napkin calculations, make it one order of magnitude harder to break. Now look how we went from 512 bits keys to 1024 bits ones.

No matter how much mathematics advance, we are still limited to processing power. Even if you figure an easier way to break a key, it still involves computing. So if you suddenly develop an alghoritm that makes it possoble to break a 2048 bits key in one minute, I'll just start using 4096 bits. I'll take whatever performance overhead that costs me, but your alghoritm will take eons to break the new key.

Again, back-of-napkin calculations have a brute force attack taking approximately 10^2045 (the numer one, followed by two thousand and forty-five zeroes) longer to break a 4096 bits key than a 2048 one. I may be a little off there, but the amount of zeroes will be close enough to give you an idea.

Okay, **I expect your attack to be a non-brute force one**, which scales more favorably than that, but even then, scaling the key up may make any attacks unfeasible for a long while - until better processors are developed, and anoter math genius comes up with another, clever method of encryption breaking.

Comment: Your answer is based on incorrect assumptions. Your basic assumption -- that the difficulty of a brute-force attack scales exponentially with key length -- holds *for algorithms where the key has no inherent structure*. That's often (but not always) the case with symmetric encryption algorithms, but it is decidedly *not* generally the case with public-key encryption algorithms. A RSA key, owing to its semiprime nature, has *significant* internal structure that allows far better attacks than brute force on the public key directly. Compare [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/).

Comment: That order-of-magnitude argument is true for brute-forcing (or any other exponential-time algorithm). However if a polynomial-time algorithm is found, that argument breaks down.